# Sprites appearing in different places

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code in one scene :

```
func setupPedestal()
    {
        // pedestal :
        pedestal            = SKSpriteNode(texture: pedestalTxt)
        pedestal.position   = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 10)
        pedestal.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: pedestalTxt.size())
        pedestal.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        pedestal.name = "pedestal"
        self.addChild(pedestal)
    }
```

this makes the pedestal appear where I want it to which is at the bottom of the screen.

Now I have the very same code on another scene and it appears in the middle. I can change the `x` value to move it across. However no matter what I put for the `y` value, it stays in the same place.

Other things such as the background isn't looping infinitely either.

Am I missing something in this new scene?

Thanks!

EDIT : Forgot to add, this is all on the same simulator for an iPhone 6.

Comment: Did you set the anchor point in any scene?

Comment: I just did a find on all the swift files for 'anchor' and couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using .sks files, check the anchor point in the scene editor. If a sprite placed at (0, 0) appears in the middle of the screen, then it indicates that the anchor point of that scene in (0.5, 0.5). I *think* that this changed with Swift 3 or Xcode 8 - before that, the default anchor point of a scene was (0.0), causing a sprite placed at (0,0) to be in the bottom-left corner, possibly off-screen.

Comment: Yep, that was it mate. Please post as an answer so I'll accept it. Thank you very much and have a nice day :)